# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have a problem with my gradle, i have try many solution that i have found on stackoverflow and other documentation but it still doesn't work, please help me

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't confuse gradle with the Android Gradle plugin.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6'
```

It is the Android Gradle plugin and **5.6 doesn't exist**.

Use the latest stable release:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

[Check the release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) for other versions.

To change the **gradle version,** edit the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

More info in [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no version 5.6 for the Gradle plugin version. The link below lists all the latest releases for the Gradle plugin versions on Google's Marvel repository.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google

I think what you mean is the distributionUrl version in your Gradle wrapper properties:

Go to your **gradle-wrapper.properties** file and complete as required:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6-all.zip
```

Then your **build.gradle** file for the project will be as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript
        {
    repositories
            {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies
            {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
}


allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```